# regex to get the value between dobj(check-2, results-5)?

Tags: regex

regex to get the value for the below string.

```
root(ROOT-0, please-1), dep(please-1, check-2), det(results-5, the-3), nn(results-5, exam-4), dobj(check-2, results-5), det(internet-8, the-7), prep_in(check-2, internet-8), dep(please-1, call-10), conj_and(check-2, call-10), dobj(call-10, me-11)
```

I need to get the parameters for dobj, i.e I want

```
check results , call me
```

Comment: Please provide a more detailed description and example of the match criteria or rules, and the regex you have tried

Comment: i have tried as  "dobj(.*)\(([^)]+)\)"
i need the values from dobj
so answer  i want is check result , call me

Comment: Not sure what language you're using this in, but this should match what you're asking for `dobj\(([a-z]+).*?([a-z]+).*?\)`. Just return groups `$1` and `$2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
(?:dobj\()([a-z]+)(?:[0-9\-]*, )([a-z]+)
```